# Everytime I run the code, Chrome opens and after a few seconds it close. Why does it close?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://translate.google.com/?hl=de")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've copied and pasted your code and it works fine with me it doesn't close. You can try adding a loop to keep the program running and if that still doesn't work try reinstalling selenium.

https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ed/9c/9030520bf6ff0b4c98988448a93c04fcbd5b13cd9520074d8ed53569ccfe/selenium-3.141.0.tar.gz